# Olap cube incorrect syntax near keyword ON

Tags: mdx, olap, cube, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I have an olap cube which i want to access. I am trying to execute mdx query. here is my simple test program:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection())
        {

            cn.ConnectionString = "secret";

            cn.Open();

            string MDX = "SELECT [Measures].[Amount] "+  " ON ROWS, " + "[Dim Client].[Common Client Name].&[test Name] "+  " ON COLUMNS " + "from [CubeName];";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(MDX, cn);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            adp.Fill(ds);
            Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]);

        }
    }
```

I am keep getting following error :  `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.` and i cant figure out what i am doing wrong. If i execute exact same query directly from management studio, cube response without errors.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `MessageBox.Show(MDX)` after the `string MDX =....` and checking what it is holding?

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode, copy the query inside string quotes ""

Answer (score 0):

Try without the concatenations and maybe use the axes index numbers, also if you are using the members caption then no need to include the ampersand:

```
string MDX = "SELECT [Measures].[Amount] ON 0, [Dim Client].[Common Client Name].[test Name] ON 1 FROM[CubeName];";
```

Does this `mdx` execute ok in `SSMS`?